# Data Refresh From Database when using TADOQuery, TClientDataSet, TDataSetProvider in Delphi

Tags: delphi, datagrid, duplicates, tclientdataset, tadoquery

I have a TADOQuery connected to a database, and sql set to fetch data.

TDataSetProvider to the above query

TClientDataSet connected to the provider

TDataSource connected to the Data set

Data source connected to a TcxGrid

The Client Data Set is also connected to a master source, that in itself is connected to a table.

I am able to add and delete to grid as expected (grid cannot be edited directly, all people can do is add or delete).  I am using delete and append on the data set to control the grid.

What is strange and I cannot solve is that when I change what record is being used in the master source grid, and then go back to the original record the data is being refreshed from the database or some stored original state of data set, rather than the in-memory data set.

So if I had deleted a record, it reappears, and any still existing ones are duplicated, though anything added from last save to database is not duplicated.  However if I do an update on the data set to the database, the database table is how I would expect.  No duplicate records, anything deleted via grid/data set is deleted, anything added is added.

I suspect this is a really trivial flag setting, but I cannot find this, and every query others have seems to be about refreshing the data, not preventing it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling ApplyUpdates on the CDS after you have added or deleted a record?

Comment: I actually just coded this to do the updates in code, essentially manually updating handling the updates.